# (Google Sheets) How to Find the Day With the Most Wins/Losses

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am building a personal trading journal with a very limited knowledge of spreadsheets formula, and decided to ask here after several failed attempts.

I want to achieve this:

| Trade Result (column A) | Trading Day (column B) |
| --- | --- |
| Win | Monday |
| Loss | Tuesday |
| Win | Monday |
| Win | Tuesday |
| Loss | Wednesday |
| Loss | Wednesday |
| Win | Monday |
| Win | Monday |
| Loss | Friday |

From above, we know that the day with the most wins: `Monday`.

Day with the most losses: `Wednesday`

How do I achieve that `Monday` for the day with the most wins, and `Wednesday` for the day with the most losses?

Appreciate the help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula-

```
=INDEX(SORT(({$B$2:$B$10,COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$10,$B$2:$B$10,$A$2:$A$10,C3)}),2,0),1,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello sir, thank you very much for the help.
Using "sort" function and referring C3 as the criterion for the countif, did not come to my mind at all.
It is now working well. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(QUERY({A:B}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,count(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col2 
  order by count(Col2) desc 
  label count(Col2)''"), 9^9, 2, 1, 0), 9^9, 2)
```

[image]